# Debugging and pre-processor directive

Tags: c++, function, class, debugging, preprocessor

Define a debug pre-processor and print enter and exit of each function including constructors and destructors if debug pre-processor is enabled.

```
class Base{ 
  public: 
    int base_int; 
 
    Base (int i){ 
        this -> base_int = i; 
    } 
 
    virtual int getInt(){ 
        return this -> base_int; 
    } 
}; 
 
class Derived : public Base{ 
  public: 
    int derived_int; 
 
    Derived (int i , int j) : Base(j){ 
            this -> derived_int = i; 
    }  
 
    int getInt(){ 
            return this -> derived_int; 
    } 
};
```

I was thinking about defining a DEBUG Macro and then adding conditions in start and end for every function, constructor, and destructor. But that is too redundant.

Comment: FYI, you only need to use `this->` syntax to differentiate parameter name and member names when they are the same name.  Additional typing may lead to more typo defects.

Comment: BTW, there's already a macro for determining a debug build vs. release build.  Search your C++ resource for "NDEBUG".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews FYI, `this->` is also used in template code to differentiate free functions/global variables from members of base class.